# File picker locations doesn't show images

Tags: xamarin.forms, filepicker

I do this on the simulator using Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker...

```
 var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
```

And it shows this...

[image]

How do I navigate to images, of which there are some on the simulator?

Comment: to select images from the device gallery, use the Media plugin

Comment: Have a try with `Xam.Plugin.Media`. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin